# Dart docs say to set Flutter SDK path in Atom dartlang settings, but no such option exists

Tags: dart, atom-editor, flutter

Under `Getting Started > Getting Flutter` at https://dart-atom.github.io/dartlang/:

"And from Atom, open the dartlang plugin’s preferences and set the Flutter SDK path to where the Flutter repo was cloned locally."

I have opened the settings for the `dartlang` plugin in Atom. There is no setting for `Flutter SDK path`. There is however a setting for `Dart SDK Location`. Is that the value that I should change to "where the flutter repo was cloned locally"? If not, where is the setting? Are the Dart docs wrong / in need of an update?

I should probably note that the `Dartlang: Create Flutter Project` command in Atom works even if this step is skipped. So I am more confused because I don't know if it's unnecessary, or I did something extra/right by accident, or this is expected but I'll run into issues later from not being able to update a setting that doesn't exist.

Comment: Flutter discontinued the Atom plugin, instead switched over to using IntelliJ. So anyone ending up here, check the new instructions for IntelliJ here:
https://flutter.io/setup/#flutter-intellij-ide-plugins

Answer (score 2):

those instructions were updated slightly before the lastest version of the atom plugin was published; you should see the Flutter SDK field in the settings now.

The process for developing with Flutter did change a bit over the weekend. You'll probably want to:

- pub global deactivate flutter
- clone the flutter repo (see http://flutter.io/getting-started/)
- set that Flutter SDK field in the atom plugin, and
- add the flutter/bin location to your system path

That first deactivate step is to ensure that you don't have copies of the pub globally activated app on your path. The new workflow instead uses a 'flutter' shell script.

Comment: I'm on version 0.4.14 of the plugin and don't see an input for "Flutter SDK".